# Connect to SQL Server on Linux (docker) using SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

How can I connect to my SQL Server which I created on Linux using docker?

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1.2
ARG source
WORKDIR /var/www/aspnetcoreapp
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AspNetCoreWithSqlOnDocker.dll"]
```

and my docker-compose:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  mssql:
    image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "p@ssw0rd1"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - 1533:1533
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  aspnetcorewithsqlondocker:
    image: aspnetcorewithsqlondocker
    ports:
      - 5001:80
    build:
      context: ./AspNetCoreWithSqlOnDocker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - mssql
    depends_on:
      - mssql
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
     driver: bridge
```

Here you can find my docker images:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect two containers inside a docker-compose, the base service must have the port exposed. And the application that requires calling the exposed container has to look like this:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  mssql:
    expose:
      - 1533

  aspnetcorewithsqlondocker:
    links:
      - mssql
```

The definition of your connection has to be:

```
HOST: mssql
PORT: 1533
```

By the way you do not have to expose the port outside unless you want to access outside the containers.